created_at must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function pgsql typeorm nestjs nodejs
I am using nestjs with typeorm pgsql.
I want to get count of my leads based on passed timezone so I am using this code:
async getEnquiryCounts(year: string, timezone: string): Promise<ApiResponseDto<any>> {
    const stats = await this.enquiryRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('enquiries')
      .select("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM enquiries.createdAt AT TIME ZONE ':timezone') as month")
      .addSelect('COUNT(*)', 'totalEnquiries')
      .addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = :newLead THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)', 'newLead')
      .addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = :docUpload THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)', 'docUpload')
      .addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = :inProgress THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)', 'inProgress')
      .addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = :rejected THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)', 'rejected')
      .addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = :agreementCreated THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)', 'agreementCreated')
      .addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = :didNotProceed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)', 'didNotProceed')
      .where("DATE_PART(\'year\', enquiries.createdAt AT TIME ZONE ':timezone') = :year", { year: year })
      .groupBy("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM enquiries.createdAt AT TIME ZONE ':timezone')")
      .setParameters({
        newLead: EnquiryStatus.NewLead.toString(),
        docUpload: EnquiryStatus.DocUpload.toString(),
        inProgress: EnquiryStatus.InProgress.toString(),
        rejected: EnquiryStatus.Rejected.toString(),
        agreementCreated: EnquiryStatus.AgreementCreated.toString(),
        didNotProceed: EnquiryStatus.DidNotProceed.toString(),
        timezone: timezone,
      })
      .getRawMany();
  
    const monthsWithData = stats.map((item) => parseInt(item.month));
    const yearRange = Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => i + 1);
  
    const finalStats = yearRange.map((month) => {
      const foundMonthIndex = monthsWithData.indexOf(month);
      if (foundMonthIndex === -1) {
        return {
          month: month.toString(),
          totalEnquiries: '0',
          rejected: '0',
          agreementCreated: '0',
          inProgress: '0',
          newLead: '0',
          docUpload: '0',
          didNotProceed: '0',
        };
      } else {
        return stats[foundMonthIndex];
      }
    });
  
    return { data: finalStats };
  }

But this is showing:
[Nest] 37372  - 06/01/2024, 12:46:36 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] column "enquiries.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
QueryFailedError: column "enquiries.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (E:\PROJECTS\backend\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:299:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

The plain query on pgsql admin like this is working:
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM enquiries.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta') AS month,
    COUNT(*) AS "totalEnquiries",
    SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = 'NewLead' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "newLead",
    SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = 'DocUpload' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "docUpload",
    SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = 'InProgress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "inProgress",
    SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = 'Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "rejected",
    SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = 'AgreementCreated' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "agreementCreated",
    SUM(CASE WHEN enquiries.status = 'DidNotProceed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "didNotProceed"
FROM 
    enquiries
WHERE 
    DATE_PART('year', enquiries.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta') = 2024
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM enquiries.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta');

This is working fine, and showing the correct results.
Any help on this or am I missing something?

Can you try enabling logging of typeorm queries to see what's actually being executed? https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging

Not sure how your ORM tool manages to mess up the query. Consider raw SQL?
Either way, this query is much better:
SELECT extract(MONTH FROM e.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta') AS month
     , count(*) AS "totalEnquiries"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE e.status = 'NewLead') AS "newLead"  -- !!!
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE e.status = 'DocUpload') AS "docUpload"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE e.status = 'InProgress') AS "inProgress"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE e.status = 'Rejected') AS "rejected"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE e.status = 'AgreementCreated') AS "agreementCreated"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE e.status = 'AgreementCreated') AS "didNotProceed"
FROM   enquiries e
WHERE  e.created_at >= timestamp '2024-1-1' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta'  -- !!!
AND    e.created_at <  timestamp '2025-1-1' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta'  -- sargable
GROUP  BY 1;

Your WHERE condition with an expression on the table column would make it needlessly expensive. Move the expression to the input side.
And the modern aggregate FILTER clause is shorter, clearer, and cheaper. See:

Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters

Aside: Avoid mixed-case identifiers in Postgres if at all possible, helps to avoid confusion. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?

